# Como receber vários valores na mesma linha?

Tags: c++

Como posso receber vários valores na mesma linha? Por exemplo, o usuário digita o número de valores e depois os valores:

> 5 (quantos valores,maior ou igual a 4)
>
> -5 1 -3 5 7 (separados por espaços em branco)

Como posso receber esses valores na mesma linha? Depois terei que trabalhar com eles.

**Problema:** http://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/programacao/nivelj/2008f2pj_acoes

Comment: Já tentou fazer alguma coisa ? Qual sua dificuldade ? Posta oque conseguiu fazer até agora. ;)

Comment: Tentei trabalhar com strings, mas tive problemas com o sinal de " - " .

Comment: tentei retirar os valores da string.

Comment: `cin >> umaVariavel` lê um dado (separando por espaços em branco). Você pode, por exemplo: 1. ler a quantidade de elementos para uma variável (e.g, `n`); 2. criar um vetor do tamanho da variável que você leu na primeira linha (e.g, `vetor[n]`); 3.  Ler cada elemento da linha dentro de um laço. 

Conforme comentário do vitor, fica bem mais fácil de te ajudar se você editar a pergunta incluindo um código de exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você quer chama alocação dinâmica de memória, ou seja, o usuário digita o número desejado e o algoritmo aloca o espaço necessário para esse vetor na memória.

No código `vetor = new int[num];` é o seu vetor. O `num` vai ser alocado de acordo com a entrada digitada.

Esse trecho:

```
 cout << "Digite os elementos do vetor: "; 
 for(i=0;i<num;i++) 
 {     
     cin >> vetor[i]; 
 }
```

Faz a leitura que você precisa.

Código de exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num; 
    int *vetor = NULL; // vetor que será alocado o espaço

    cout << "Digite o tamanho do vetor: \n";
    cin >> num;

    vetor = new int[num];

    int i;

    cout << "Digite os elementos do vetor: "; 
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        cin >> vetor[i]; 
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Digite os números " << i << ": "; 

    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
       cout << vetor[i] << endl;
    }

    delete [] vetor;  // Libera o espaço alocado para o vetor
    return 0; 
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6ZcCUL).

Lembre-se que é importante usar `delete [] vetor;` para liberar a memória.

Comment: O problema é que eu posso receber 50/100 valores.

Comment: Você quer um algoritmo que você passe o tamanho do vetor?

Comment: Preciso de um algorítimo que receba n números (n>=4) na mesma linha, sendo n definido pelo usuário. Depois preciso "trabalhar" com esses números. Como posso receber esses n números na mesma linha, de forma que depois eu possa "trabalhar" com os mesmos?

Comment: Entendi, vou editar a resposta

Comment: 6 (Quantidade de números que irá ser informada pelo usuário)
1 2 3 4 -5 -6 (números informados pelo usuário)
Agora preciso "trabalhar" com esses números, como posso recebe-los de forma que seja possível "trabalhar" com eles?

Comment: @GabrielPastori, esse é um exemplo de leitura e escrita pra você ter uma base.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução um pouco mais idiomática evitando usar new/delete e arrays nativos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int vecSize; 

   cout << "Digite o tamanho do vetor: ";
   cin >> vecSize;

   vector<int> vetor;
   cout << "Digite os elementos do vetor: "; 

   for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
   {
      int val;
      cin >> val;
      vetor.push_back(val);
   }

   cout << endl;
   cout << "Números digitados (" << vetor.size() << "):\n";

   for (int num : vetor)
   {
      cout << num << endl;
   }

}
```

Na prática, quando se faz entrada de dados sempre se faz consistência dos valores lidos, então um exemplo um pouco mais realista seria esse abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum { MAX_VEC_SIZE = 100 };

int main()
{
   int vecSize;

   // -------

   // leitura do tamanho do vetor

   cout << "\nDigite o tamanho do vetor: ";

   if (!(cin >> vecSize))
   {
      cerr << "erro na leitura do tamanho do vetor\n";
      exit(1);
   }

   if (vecSize < 1)
   {
      cerr << "erro, tamanho do vetor precisa ser maior que zero\n";
      exit(1);
   }

   if (vecSize > MAX_VEC_SIZE)
   {
      cerr << "erro, tamanho do vetor deve ser menor que " << (MAX_VEC_SIZE+1) << "\n";
      exit(1);
   }

   // -------

   // leitura dos elementos do vetor

   vector<int> vetor;
   cout << "\nDigite os elementos do vetor:\n";

   for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
   {
      int val;
      if (!(cin >> val))
      {
         cerr << "erro na leitura do elemento " << i << " do vetor\n";
         exit(1);
      }
      vetor.push_back(val);
   }

   // -------

   // exibicao dos elementos do vetor

   cout << "\nElementos do vetor (" << vetor.size() << "):\n";

   for (int num : vetor)
   {
      cout << num << endl;
   }

   // -------

}
```

That's all for now folks.